# Different ways to express 'if A happens'

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between "*soshite*", "*suruto*" and "*sorede*"?
I am unable to distinguish the used-cases - they all seem to indicate 'If A happens then...'

> jibun no koto o otona da to omoimasu ka?
> ........, 10 nin chuu 8 nin ga etc etc

What would be the appropriate conjunction here?

Comment: When used at the beginning of a sentence, in reference to the immediately preceding sentence, you mean?  Do you have examples of the sentences that are causing you confusion?

Comment: hmm. is this some sort of quiz question or practice question? Unfortunately, although I can 'sense' which of the three is the best choice, I'm not sure I can explain why. There are subtle differences ... you might not think it, but the part where you wrote "etc etc" might actually be important for choosing which one, because a LOT of information can be conveyed in the last few words of a Japanese sentence.

Comment: None of those three conjunctions work in the example. You should explicit your question if it's "difference among sosite, suruto and sorede" or "what conjunction is appropriate".

Comment: @user4092 ... one of them might work, if there is missing information, for example, if the whole statement goes something like: A survey asked young people between the ages of 14 and 18 "Do you consider yourself an adult?" and then/from that/following that 8 out of 10 people replied.... " The missing information would probably clear up whether a mistake is being made or not...

Answer (score 1):

I am certain that a Japanese native will at some point put out a more accurate or informative answer than this, but since no one has yet...

そして{soshite}, すると{suruto}, and それで{sorede} are roughly synonymous, meaning essentially "and then":

**そして**, commonly meaning "**and/then/and then**" or a more word-for-word translation being "**after that is/was done**" is commonly put between two actions, to show the **order** of "first this, then that":

> ケーキ{keeki}を{wo}作って{tsukutte}、そして{soshite}パーティー{paatii}の{no}じゅんび{junbi}を{wo}した{shita}。
>
> I baked a cake, **then** prepared for the party.

it can also be used before the last word in a list of two or more nouns or noun phrases to link all of them, grouping them together with the verb or adjective that follows:

> この{kono}がっこう{gakkou}は{wa}びじゅつぶ{bijutsu bu}、テニスぶ{tennis bu}、そして{soshite}けんどうぶ{kendo bu}、ぜんぶ{zembu}が{ga}ゆうめい{yuumei}です{desu}。
>
> At this school, the art club, tennis club, **and** kendo club are all famous.

すると{suruto}, and それで{sorede} are both words that can mean something a little more "literary", such as: "**thereupon**" as well as "**with that/following that/from that**" **すると** is put between two actions, or at the start of a new sentence, to show that the actions before it and after it are linked, either in **order** by time, the same way as そして{soshite},  or even more specifically in the case of **それで** as a **cause/effect** relationship.

> アラジン{Alladin}は{wa}ランプ{lamp}を{o}こすった{kosutta}。すると{suruto}、ジニー{genie}が{ga}とうじょう{toujou}した{shita}。
>
> Alladin rubbed the lamp. **Following that**, a genie appeared.

Another usage, though not one I personally have heard often, is to mean something along the lines of "**Well then,**" or "**So,**" ...at the beginning a sentence:

> すると{suruto}、あなた{anata}は{wa}なに{nani}を{o}した{shita}か{ka}？
>
> **So,** what did you do **(then)**?
> **So then**, what did you do?
> **Well then**, what did you do?

To my knowledge, **すると**, and **それで** are almost interchangeable, except that it seems, (from my experience) that while すると can start a sentence or phrase OR be "attached" to a verb mid-sentence in its linking function, それで is placed at the beginning of a sentence or phrase, and does not "attach" to verbs like すると:

> あの{ano}こ{ko}と{to}はなし{hanashisuruto}**すると**、やっと{yatto}わかった{wakatta}。
> あの{ano}こ{ko}と{to}はなした{hanashita}。**すると**、やっと{suruto yatto}わかった{wakatta}。
> あの{ano}こ{ko}と{to}はなした{hanashita}。**それで**やっと{sorede yatto}わかった{wakatta}。
>
> I spoke to (her/that child), **and (then/from that)** I finally understood.

Comment: けんど is "gladiator" while "kendo" is けんどう. すると doesn't mean "so". それで means that the first clause is a trigger for the second one, while すると just means that two events happened in that order.

Comment: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-544076  if "suruto" can "imply the derivation of a result from a previously discussed matter" as kotobank says, then it CAN be translated as "so" or "well then" or any other number of phrases in English which show that the speaker is discussing what they believe to be a result of something which was discussed earlier. Not that I have often heard it used in this form, but it does make sense. I am grateful for the differentiation between  すると and それで though.

Comment: Although perhaps すると in the case above has to be followed specifically by  the speaker's guess about the result of an action, rather than a simple question...

Comment: You can't use それで in the second example of すると that's rephrased as それでは besides, which translates "if so". The point is sense of "if", which それで doesn't have but すると and それでは have. (I knew English "actually" doesn't distinguish 実際(に)は from 実際に. Now I've realized this is also the case with "so", which I ignored when I wrote "すると doesn't mean so". I've learned something new too.)

Comment: you mean that "あのことはなした。それでやっとわかった。" should actually be "あのことはなした。それで**は**やっとわかった。" ?  I was trying to use those 3 sentences to show that すると can be mid-sentence but それで has to be at the beginning of a sentence... how can I correct this to show what I mean?

Comment: I meant the second usage explained here https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-544076

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79656/discussion-between-user4092-and-ericfromabeno).